# Phonegap/Cordova: How to add Javascript Multi-Touch Events?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, touch

I'm trying to make a simple app using Cordova. Since the beginning I've been using the:

```
c.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
    mouseDown();
}, false);
```

method. But the problem is that

1. I can not specify coordinates (otherwise doesn't work at all)
2. The touch executes only when I "release" my finger, rather than executing right away when screen is touched.

I'm a huge amateur and I can't find any answers on how to properly handle touch events.

In summary, I want to use Touch (like a mouse click) with coordinates, and use multitouch events, such as -> 2 fingers swipe outward = "zoom out", 2 fingers swipe inward = "zoom in" stuff.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library that lets you handle all kind of touch events like [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) or like I use to do, you can download a custom build of jquery mobile only with the methods that lets you handle that.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the quick reply ivillamil, I will give it a try :)

Comment: I copy pasted the code into a hammer.js file and referenced it in my index.html under <head>:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.js"></script>`
Then I added into my main js file:
`var hammertime = new Hammer(c);
hammertime.on('tap', function(event){
/*Do something*/
});`
Program doesn't work anymore, even after undoing everything :( Also tried add/remove platform android.. Am I missing something?